# Excel: Get rid of gaps in line chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have a table that contains the data with some absent values. If I create a line chart for that, there are gaps in place of absent values, but I'd like to have the line just follow through to the next value. Is there a *standard and simple* way to do this without touching the data (e.g. using settings for the chart)? I'm able to solve this using additional column with calculated values for the gaps, just wondering if there's an easy way.

[image]

I'm using Office 365, if that matters.

Comment: There really isn't a way to do this outside of what you've already described. On another note, I'd caution against this, as connecting the dots (so to speak) can infer that there is data that doesn't really exist, and can be misleading.

Comment: Yep, exactly that's why I would prefer a solution that would draw the line through without actually adding the dot; so it should connect any two non-empty adjacent data points, not just ones that follow right one after another.

Comment: Perhaps a line chart is not the correct option? With missing values if you add the line then you are suggesting values are there... Perhaps you'd be better off supplementing the line chart with a trend-line?

Comment: Line chart is just fine for my case. Perhaps, it would be illustrated better if line chart with markers was used.

Comment: I would absolutely add the data point markers, then use a lighter shaded line to help emphasize the difference between actual data (your points) and interpolation (your lines).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Excel 2010 there is a fairly simple way to do this. First go to the "Select data source"-dialog (rightclick chart > Select data), and select the button "Hidden and empty cells:
[image]

In the dialog which pops up, switch the selection from "Gaps" to "Connect data points with line".
[image]

Click "OK" for both the dialogs, and you are done!

Comment: This feature is also on Excel 2007; don't know how I missed it.  I'm deleting my answer because this is obviously the best solution.